# Change a config file through a http server

Tags: linux, http-server

hey, first sorry for my bad english, and I do not know if the best place for this is here or stackoverflow :/  - I need to do a webpage on which someone can change a file on a linux machine. Think in a page that you can access from other computers and check a checkbox to enable/disable squid or something like that. I already have a debian VM running (no GUI). The problem is i dont even know where to start, I have little experience with linux (would know how to do that on windows, with iis+php or asp.net) - Another problem is that I need to use as little resources from the machine as possible because its a small computer. Dont need to be fancy, i only need a http server to show me some pages and a server-side language so I can make things happen. Well, maybe a little fancy because I need to change some files as root, so i need some kind of auth as well - What is the most simple way to do that (if any)? nginx, lighttpd, other? And to do the work? (I suppose I can use PHP, but feels like it is to heavy just for this simple task...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for a small web server, like nginx, running a simple cgi or wsgi script which modifies the files there. You can do simple auth (with a single password) within a one-file script fairly securely, provided that you never make the contents of the script public.

You may want to ask on Stack Overflow for more help with the programming aspects of your question.  If you don't know where to start, that's probably the biggest obstacle to getting this done.

Comment: thank you Kedeki, i have sucessfully installed nginx on debian, the config file is simple, so now i have the server running. But while researching how to install wsgi, I found CherryPy project that looks like a better solution for me. Thanks anyway, your tip gave me the right  direction :)